# Hazelcast Discovery multicast error in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I have a problem with the comunication of 2 pods with hazelcast, my hazelcast.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  ~ Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
  ~
  ~ Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  ~ you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  ~ You may obtain a copy of the License at
  ~
  ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  ~
  ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  ~ distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  ~ WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  ~ See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  ~ limitations under the License.
  -->

<hazelcast xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config hazelcast-config-3.11.xsd"
           xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <management-center> enabled="the url of my manager center</management-center>
</hazelcast>
```

The pods with hazelcast have a service which his endpoints are the pods with hazelcast. But each pod with hazelcast cant see the other, I have tried to include this in hazelcast.xml:

```
<network>
<join>
     <multicast enabled="true">
                <multicast-group>service_name.namespace.svc.cluster.local</multicast-group>
                <multicast-port>5701</multicast-port>
            </multicast>
    </join>
</network>
```

where service_name is the service name which his endpoints are hazelcast pods and namespace my namespace, but hazelcast pod gives me this error:

```
SEVERE: 
[3.12.13-SNAPSHOT] Not a multicast address
java.net.SocketException: Not a multicast address
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes usually does not support multicast, therefore to set up Hazelcast cluster you should use the Hazelcast Kubernetes plugin for discovery.

Please check the following link to get more details on the ways you can configure it: https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/latest/deploy/deploying-in-kubernetes

Comment: that gives me error: saying I have more than 1 join method, but I only put he join kubernetes tag